# my frame are shown side by side. I want to show just one on top and switch them through a button

Tags: python, tkinter

I use tkinter and every frames only have 1 image, 1 label and 1 button(that switches from frame to frame) they are all shown together side by side. the Label is the only element that change as I click the Button. can anyone help me put just one of them on top?

this is my code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)
class main(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand= True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = { }

        for F in (StartPage, Pageone):

            frame = F(parent= container, controller= self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)


    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        Label = tk.Label(self, text= "that's the first frame", font = LARGE_FONT)
        Label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        Button= ttk.Button(text= "visit page 1", command= lambda: controller.show_frame(Pageone))
        Button.pack()
        image = Image.open(r'/Users/me/Documents/pythonfolder/kushina.jpg')
        image.thumbnail((300,300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        Label_image = tk.Label(image=photo)
        Label_image.image = photo
        Label_image.pack()



class Pageone(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        Label = tk.Label(self, text= "that's the second frame", font = LARGE_FONT)
        Label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        Button= ttk.Button(text= "back to home", command= lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        Button.pack()
        image = Image.open(r'/Users/me/Documents/pythonfolder/kushina3.jpg')
        image.thumbnail((300,300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        Label_image = tk.Label(image=photo)
        Label_image.image = photo
        Label_image.pack()

app = main()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: please fix the markup around your code. You have some code that is properly highlighted, some that is not.

Answer (score 1):

Pass parent to your widget initiation, or by default they'll be placed inside the root window `Tk` instance. Replace:

```
Button= ttk.Button(text= "visit page 1", ...)
```

with:

```
Button = ttk.Button(self, text= "visit page 1", ...)
```